# How can I tell when my computer was manufactured.?

Tags: date

I want to install a  operating system
 and my computer must be manufactured between 2006 and 2014.  How can I tell when it was manufactured?

Comment: Bios may contain manufacture date under one of the menu's. If not it should be on the motherboard. Instead of looking at manufacture date try looking at required specs eg. cpu, ram etc....

Comment: Did you try to Google this?

Answer (score 0):

Year of manufacture doesn't always give you an accurate indication of whether you can run a new OS or not.  The spec of the hardware within the PC does.  That said, the year of manufacture will allow you to ballpark these things

Try searching for the make and model of the PC if it says on the case?  Thsi will give you a rough ballpark of the year of manufacture - hardware doesn't last long before it is superceeded

Try checking your BIOS menu to see if you can get a year of manufacture or a copyright date, the (C)1999-2006 will tell you that your PC was probably in the 2005-7 region (within a year or so of the upper boundary)

There is also the possibility that if you open the case and look at things like the hard drive, it will have a year of manufacture on it.

If you can get some component names and models, you can ballpark when the machine was made by looking at availability dates from manufacturers for those parts.

Let me know how you get on.